# Using FFMPEG to add subtitles to a M4v video file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, subtitles

I am having troubles adding subtitles to a video file using ffmpeg.

I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i movie_input.m4v -newsubtitle subtitles.srt -acodec copy -vcodec copy movie_output.m4v
```

I found this command line example in various tutorials but for some reason (a newer version of ffmpeg?) it gives me:

```
Unrecognized option 'newsubtitle'
```

Any clue as to how can I add subtitles using ffmpeg?

Thanks!

P.S. I need a solution that can be automated in a bash script, so using programs like Subler are not fit for this task.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-newsubtitle` is an obsolete option from old versions of ffmpeg; with more modern versions, the command will look like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4v -i subtitle.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:s mov_text output.m4v
```

`-i input.m4v -i subtitle.srt` tells ffmpeg to use those two files as its inputs.

`-map 0 -map 1` tells ffmpeg to use all the streams from input number 0 and input number 1.

It's not directly relevant to this, but you can select individual streams with `-map`: `-map 0:v` would select all video streams from input 0, `-map 1:s` would select all subtitle streams from input 1, `-map 0:0` would select stream 0 (the first stream) from input 0, `-map 1:a:0` would select the first audio stream of input 1.

`-c copy` tells ffmpeg to copy all streams from the input without re-encoding, while having `-c:s mov_text` *after* the `-c copy` overrides the copy setting for the subtitle stream, re-encoding it to a form the MP4 container can contain.

Comment: Is there a way to burn-in the subtitles to a m4v file using ffmpeg?

Comment: @KorayTugay [Yes](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo). If you need any help not contained in that link, feel free to [ask a question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) (and don't forget to tag it with `ffmpeg`).

Comment: I am confused because examples here do not contain m4v.

Answer (score 6):

With FFmpeg 0.9, the `-newsubtitle` option was removed. If you want to add all input files' video/audio/subtitle streams to the output, use the `-map` options, e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i movie_input.m4v -i subtitles.srt -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text \
-map 0 -map 1 out.m4v
```

This will copy video and audio streams, but encode the subtitles to `mov_text`, which is the only officially supported subtitle format for MP4. SRT by default won't work.

The `map` options here specify that all the streams from the first file (`0`) and the second file (`1`) will be copied, so it'd work even if your original had multiple audio streams, for example.

For a detailed article on how to use the `map` option, [see the FFmpeg wiki](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20use%20-map%20option).

<sub>Reason for removing those options [from the Changelog](https://raw.github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/master/Changelog):</sub>

> <sub>-newvideo/-newaudio/-newsubtitle options were removed. Not only were they
>         irregular and highly confusing, they were also redundant. In avconv the -map
>         option will create new streams in the output file and map input streams to
>         them. E.g. avconv -i INPUT -map 0 OUTPUT will create an output stream for
>         each stream in the first input file.</sub>