# Adding subtitles via command line in ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, subtitles

I'm trying to loop, via batch file, through all my folders and, where external subtitle files are present, merge them into existing files.
Subtitles could be srt/sub/idx/etc., basically any format.
Most are English, but a few are other languages.
The video files could be MP4, MKV, AVI. (Understood that ffmpeg might not support all of these.)

I don't want to "burn in" the subtitles, I just want them available.

If possible, I don't want to reencode any of the files, just add in the subtitles so I don't need the separate subtitle files.

I'd appreciate it someone could share the proper-syntax command line to do this.

I have the (however inelegant) framework (batch file), basically:

```
For /R %%A in (D:\Movies) Do (
If Exist %%~dpn.srt (
[awaiting ffmpeg CLI syntax]
Del %%~dpn.srt
)
For /R %%B in ("%%~dpn.*Eng.srt") Do (
[awaiting ffmpeg CLI syntax]
Del %%B
)
If Exist %%~dpn.*Ita.srt (
[awaiting ffmpeg CLI syntax]
Del %%~dpn.srt
)
For /R %%B in ("%%~dpn.*Ita.srt") Do (
[awaiting ffmpeg CLI syntax]
Del %%B
)
If Exist %%~dpn.sub (
[awaiting ffmpeg CLI syntax]
Del %%~dpn.srt
)
If Exist %%~dpn.idx (
[awaiting ffmpeg CLI syntax]
Del %%~dpn.srt
)
[repeat for each subtitle format]
)
```

What I'm missing is a simple clear understanding of the CLI to only embed (but not "burn in") the subtitles, without otherwise re-encoding each file (or, if re-encoding, need to make sure the file does not significantly grow).

Appreciate your help in advance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of existing posts about the same task:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672809/use-ffmpeg-to-add-text-subtitles
- [Using FFMPEG to add subtitles to a M4v video file](https://superuser.com/questions/549179/using-ffmpeg-to-add-subtitles-to-a-m4v-video-file)
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/subtitle_options
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/214199/how-do-i-add-and-or-keep-subtitles-when-converting-video/214351
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/22197/ffmpeg-how-to-add-several-subtitle-streams
- https://www.reck.dk/use-ffmpeg-to-add-subtitles-to-video/

Basically you just specify both files as inputs using **`-i`** and ffmpeg will create a combined file which contains all of the input streams it finds.

Note that not all containers support all subtitle types, and some might need a special option. For example, if you're writing to an MP4 file, you'll need **`-c:s mov_text`** to convert SUB/SRT into MP4's interna' subtitle format. If you have fancy-formatted SSA (.ass) subtitles, they can only be added to .mkv containers.

To avoid re-encoding, make sure to use the "copy" codec: **`-c:a copy`** and **`-c:v copy`**. Also avoid referring to any posts which mention "hardsubs"; do not use `-vf`.

Comment: Thank you. My Googling proved insufficient compared to yours, plus my original efforts may have been confused by ... well, forgetting about Windows Controlled folder access. Thanks again!